# Is it possible to create an HTML slideshow where you name the div, rather than refer to them by numbers?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a slide show similar to [this one by w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/tryit.asp?filename=tryw3css_slideshow_imgdots).

Except I have a lot more slides in mine. I also have seperate buttons that take you to a specific slide. So if I do: `onclick="currentDiv(5)"` then add in a slide at the beginning the button will go to the wrong slide. I'm looking for a way to do something like: `onclick="currentDiv(forrest)"`

EDIT:

Sorry if I was too broad. I'll try and elaborate. I'm currently learning html and trying to learn javascript, css and php as I go. But I haven't learned enough to change my existing script to do this. I'll try and be a bit more specific. I have a bunch of slides. I added buttons that take you to a specific slide. So I have a button that takes you to slide 7. The problem is if I add a new slide, say at position 3, it will bump the rest of the slides out of order. The old slide 6 is now 7. So the button I had refers to the old slide 6 at it's new position of 7. The button doesn't know that slide 7 moved to 8. If I could do something like onclick="currentDiv(forrest)" it wouldn't matter if the order changed.

Comment: There are essentially any number of ways this could be implemented. As it stands the question is too broad.

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fp39h2yk/ (also: yes, it's obviously possible. it's trivial. the answer is to learn JavaScript, not copy-paste scripts from w3schools)

Comment: @ChrisG As a note: Even though it will work, `name` is not a valid attribute for an `img`-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@ChrisG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g) solved this for me. I'm just posting the answer here for future reference and to mark it solved. Thanks Chris!

> Here's a fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/fp39h2yk](http://jsfiddle.net/fp39h2yk) (also: yes, it's obviously possible. it's trivial. the answer is to learn JavaScript, not copy-paste scripts from w3schools)

HTML:

```
<button onclick="currentDiv('forest');">
  Forest
</button>

<div class="w3-content" style="max-width:1200px">
  <img name="city" class="mySlides" src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img name="mountains" class="mySlides" src="img_fjords_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img name="forest" class="mySlides" src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function currentDiv(n) {
  if (isNaN(n)) {
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var found = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      if (slides[i].getAttribute("name") == n) {
        found = i + 1;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (!found) return;
    n = found;
  }
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  alert("showing slide " + n);
}
```